[pyspark ]MutableFloat cannot be cast to MutableDouble while merging parquet files
I have many parquet files inside a S3 folder. Each one has 'A', 'B', 'C' Columns. 'A' and 'B' columns have string data type but 'C' column has Float type in some and Double in others. I want to merge these parquet files and create larger one. I am doing this merge inside AWS Glue using pyspark.
When I try to write the Dataframe into S3 using
     output_s3_path = "s3://new_path/"
     df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(output_s3_path)

I am getting error
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.MutableFloat cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.MutableDouble at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.SpecificInternalRow.setDouble(SpecificInternalRow.scala:284)
I tried with following ways

spark.read.option("mergeSchema", "true") to merge the schema, ex:
s3_df = spark.read.option("overwriteSchema", "true").parquet("s3://path/")

spark.read.option("overwriteSchema", "true") to overite the schema with new data type

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.enableVectorizedReader","false") 


But not of them worked. Setting the schema expilicitely would not a better solution for me as I expect to merge many different parquet file sets using the same solution.
How can I solve this issue?

Did you fin a solution?

try using df = df.withColumn("C", F.col("C").cast("double")) in pyspark.
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# Initialize Glue context and job
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

# S3 paths
input_path = "s3://your-input-bucket/path-to-parquet-files/"
output_path = "s3://your-output-bucket/path-to-merged-parquet-file/"

# Read the parquet files into a DynamicFrame
dyf = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    connection_type="s3",
    connection_options={"paths": [input_path]},
    format="parquet"
)

# Convert DynamicFrame to DataFrame
df = dyf.toDF()

# Cast the 'C' column to Double to ensure consistency
df = df.withColumn("C", F.col("C").cast("double"))

# Convert DataFrame back to DynamicFrame
dyf_cleaned = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df, glueContext, "dyf_cleaned")

# Write the merged data back to S3
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame=dyf_cleaned,
    connection_type="s3",
    connection_options={"path": output_path},
    format="parquet"
)

# Commit the job
job.commit()

